# How to compute $\int \mbox{arcsec} \left(-\sin^2x \right)\,{\rm d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone please help me solve the following integral?

$$\int \mbox{arcsec} \left(-\sin^2x \right)\,{\rm d}x$$

I have a doubt about the validity of this question. Because $\sin^2(x)$ has range $[0,1]$ but $\mbox{arcsec}(y)$
has domain $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: FYI a "simpler" version $\int \sec^{-1}(-\sin x) dx$ is already non-expressive in elementary functions, and Mathematica/Sage gives `x*ArcSec[-Sin[x]] - Sqrt[-Cot[x]^2]*(x*(Log[1 - E^(I*x)] - Log[1 + E^(I*x)]) + I*PolyLog[2, -E^(I*x)] - I*PolyLog[2, E^(I*x)])*Tan[x]` (Note the PolyLog), so I am quite certain the integral will not have any closed form.

Comment: I put it in a computer system and it took way too long to even process with 4.5GhZ power. Maybe it's wrong and certainly cannot be calculated by hand.

Comment: It's invalid over the real numbers, but over the complex numbers $arcsec(z) = -i \ln (i \sqrt{1 - z^{-2}} + \frac{1}{z})$.

Like other comments have said it's very unlikely that this has a nice closed form, but it is valid over the complex numbers.